# How can I extract the values of the last aggregation date in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table.

```
id  user    time_stamp                 
1   Mike    2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC     
2   John    2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC      
3   Levy    2020-02-12 00:00:00 UTC      
4   Sam     2020-02-12 00:00:00 UTC      
5   Frodo   2020-02-11 00:00:00 UTC
```

Let's say 2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC is the last day and I would like to query this table to only display last days results? I want to create a view in Bigquery so that I only and always get the last day's results?

So that in the end I get something like this (For last day which is 2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC )

```
id  user    time_stamp                 
1   Mike    2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC     
2   John    2020-02-13 00:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by time_stamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This may not work well on a large amount of data -- because of the way that BQ implements window functions with no partitioning.  So, you might find that this works better (especially if the above runs out of resources):

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select max(time_stamp) as max_time_stamp
      from t
     ) tt
     on t.time_stamp = max_time_stamp;
```

Also, if the timestamps actually have date components, then you will want to convert to a `date` or remove the time component somehow.